# How find the maximum of the value $t$ such $x^3+y^3+z^3+t(xy^2+yz^2+zx^2)\ge (1+t)(x^2y+y^2z+z^2x)$

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, buffalo-way

let $x,y,z\ge 0$, find the maximum of the $t$, such 
$$x^3+y^3+z^3+t(xy^2+yz^2+zx^2)\ge (1+t)(x^2y+y^2z+z^2x)$$

maybe this take $y=x+u,z=x+t$,But I can't get the answer,because this is very ugly, Thanks

Comment: This is a very simple inequality of the type $a+bt \geq (1+t)b$. I think you are just over thinking.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is Mongolian TST 2008. If so, you can read the solution [in this pdf, problem 6](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&ved=2ahUKEwi0iPfO19roAhUgJjQIHeoPBUo4ChAWMAN6BAgFEAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdiendantoanhoc.net%2Findex.php%3Fapp%3Dcore%26module%3Dattach%26section%3Dattach%26attach_id%3D15237&usg=AOvVaw0XijBGGQNZH-E3KbFQv5w8). P.S. Please clarify if $x, y, z$ are fixed real values, or if $x, y, z$ are meant to range from $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: Perhaps you have some problem with English and you wanted to say : find the maximum value of $t$ such that the inequality holds **whenver** $x,y ,z \geq 0$. This is not what you has written in the question. Some guys with poor knowledge of English and logic downvoted may correct answer so I deleted it.

Comment: $\forall x, y, z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that it means that we need to find a maximal value of $t$, for which this inequality is true for any non-negatives $x$, $y$ and $z$.

If so, we can say that your way (BW) helps!

Let $x=\min\{x,y,z\}$, $y=x+u$, $z=x+v$ and $u=kv$.

Thus, $u$ and $v$ are non-negatives and $$\sum_{cyc}(x^2+txy^2-(t+1)x^2y)=$$
$$=2(u^2-uv+v^2)x+u^3-(t+1)u^2v+tuv^2+v^3\geq$$
$$\geq u^3-(t+1)u^2v+tuv^2+v^3=v^3(k^3-(t+1)k^2+tk+1).$$
Id est, it's enough to find a maximal value of $t$, for which the inequality $$k^3-(t+1)k^2+tk+1\geq0$$ is true for any non-negative value of $k$ or
$$k^3-k^2+1\geq t(k^2-k).$$
Now, it's enough to assume $k>1$ and it's remains to find$$\min_{k>1}\frac{k^3-k^2+1}{k^2-k}.$$
Can you end it now?

I got $$t_{max}=\frac{\sqrt{13+16\sqrt2}-1}{2}\approx2.484...$$

Comment: This is not the the correct answer since OP did not ask us to find the maximum  value of $t$ so that the inequlaity holds **for all $x,y,z \geq 0$**. OP is fixing $x,y,z$ and asking for the maximum value of $t$.

Comment: What I am saying is that if if go by the actual wording of the question we have to find the maximum value of $t$ as  a function of $x,y,z$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy I underdstood your point. It means that we need to find a maximal value of $t$, for which the inequality is true for any non-negative variables. See attempts of the topic starter. We can see that he meant just my formulation.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

I assumed again that it means that we need to find a maximal value of $t$, for which our inequality is true for any non-negatives $x$, $y$ and $z$.

Indeed, our inequality it's $$\sum_{cyc}(x^3+tx^2z-(t+1)x^2y)\geq0$$ or

$$\sum_{cyc}(2x^3+2tx^2z-2(t+1)x^2y)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2x^3-x^2y-x^2z)\geq(2t+1)\sum_{cyc}(x^2y-x^2z)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x+y)(x-y)^2\geq(2t+1)(x-y)(x-z)(y-z),$$ which says that it's enough to understand, what happens for $x\geq y\geq z$.

But in this case $$(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)\leq(x-y)xy$$ and if we'll decrease our variables by $z$, so the left side will be less and the right side will be greater.

Thus, it's enough to understand, what happens for $z=0$ and we got a previous problem:

To find a maximal value of $t$, for which the inequality $$x^3+y^3+txy^2-(t+1)xy^2\geq0$$ is true for any non-negative numbers $x$ and $y$.